# Setup WSO2 IS 5.0.0 using JDBC as the primary datastore

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure WSO2 IS 5.0.0 to use a mysql database as the default primary datasource.

I have reviewed the following guides from the documentation:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Setting+up+MySQL
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+a+JDBC+User+Store

I receive the following error when I try to login as admin via the admin website:

Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2015-01-08 22:31:03,647-0500]

This is a fresh install of WSO2IS 5.0.0. The database was initialized using the -Dsetup property. The UM_USER table shows the admin user exists. I have configured the mysql datasource in master-datasource.xml, disabled the embedded ldap server in embedded-ldap.xml, and commented out the ldap tenant in tenant-mgt.xml.

When I start the server I do not see any errors aside from the login warning noted above. The database also appears to have all the information, but the admin web application does not let me login as admin.

I also noticed that the tenant id is -1234. Is that an expected default or indicate a potential multi-tenant error?

Here's my user-mgt.xml

```
<UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
                <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
                <AdminRole>[Role]</AdminRole>
                <AdminUser>
                     <UserName>[userName]</UserName>
                     <Password>[password]</Password>
                </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        </Configuration>
        <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="IsEmailUserName">false</Property>
            <Property name="DomainCalculation">default</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
            <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{8,50}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{8,50}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="SharedGroupEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
        </UserStoreManager>
        <AuthorizationManager
            class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
            <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
            <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        </AuthorizationManager>
    </Realm>
</UserManager>
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same issue when using MYSQL DB.

Answer (score 3):

This morning I got connect IS with MySQL.

I used this references:

http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com.es/2013/09/deploying-identity-server-over-jdbc.html

Anyway, I'll share my configuration  if it's any help:

In user-mgt.xml:

```
<Realm>
    <Configuration>
    <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                 <UserName>admin</UserName>
                 <Password>admin</Password>
            </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        <name>jdbc/JDBC_User_Store</name>
        <Property name="MultiTenantRealmConfigBuilder">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.multitenancy.SimpleRealmConfigBuilder</Property>
    </Configuration>

    <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
          <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
          <Property name="driverName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Property>
          <Property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JDBC_User_Store</Property>
          <Property name="userName">root</Property>
          <Property name="password">root</Property>
          <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>
          <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
          <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
          <Property name="maxActive">50</Property>
            <Property name="maxWait">60000</Property>
            <Property name="minIdle">5</Property>
          <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
          <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
          <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
          <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
          <Property name="IsEmailUserName">false</Property>
          <Property name="DomainCalculation">default</Property>
          <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
          <Property name="WriteGroups">false</Property>
          <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
          <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
          <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
          <Property name="SelectUserSQL">SELECT * FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetRoleListSQL">SELECT UM_ROLE_NAME, UM_TENANT_ID, UM_SHARED_ROLE FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME LIKE ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_SHARED_ROLE ='0' ORDER BY UM_ROLE_NAME</Property>
          <Property name="GetSharedRoleListSQL">SELECT UM_ROLE_NAME, UM_TENANT_ID, UM_SHARED_ROLE FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME LIKE ? AND UM_SHARED_ROLE ='1' ORDER BY UM_ROLE_NAME</Property>
          <Property name="UserFilterSQL">SELECT UM_USER_NAME FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME LIKE ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=? ORDER BY UM_USER_NAME</Property>
          <Property name="UserRoleSQL">SELECT UM_ROLE_NAME FROM UM_USER_ROLE, UM_ROLE, UM_USER WHERE UM_USER.UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_USER.UM_ID=UM_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_ID AND UM_ROLE.UM_ID=UM_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_ID AND UM_USER_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="UserSharedRoleSQL">SELECT UM_ROLE_NAME, UM_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID, UM_SHARED_ROLE FROM UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE INNER JOIN UM_USER ON UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_ID = UM_USER.UM_ID INNER JOIN UM_ROLE ON UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_ID = UM_ROLE.UM_ID WHERE UM_USER.UM_USER_NAME = ? AND UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_TENANT_ID = UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID AND UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_TENANT_ID = UM_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID AND UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_TENANT_ID = ?</Property>
          <Property name="IsRoleExistingSQL">SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserListOfRoleSQL">SELECT UM_USER_NAME FROM UM_USER_ROLE, UM_ROLE, UM_USER WHERE UM_ROLE.UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_USER.UM_ID=UM_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_ID AND UM_ROLE.UM_ID=UM_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_ID AND UM_USER_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserListOfSharedRoleSQL">SELECT UM_USER_NAME FROM UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE INNER JOIN UM_USER ON UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_ID = UM_USER.UM_ID INNER JOIN UM_ROLE ON UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_ID = UM_ROLE.UM_ID WHERE UM_ROLE.UM_ROLE_NAME= ? AND UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_USER_TENANT_ID = UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID AND UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_TENANT_ID = UM_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID</Property>
          <Property name="IsUserExistingSQL">SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserPropertiesForProfileSQL">SELECT UM_ATTR_NAME, UM_ATTR_VALUE FROM UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE, UM_USER WHERE UM_USER.UM_ID = UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_USER_ID AND UM_USER.UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_PROFILE_ID=? AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserPropertyForProfileSQL">SELECT UM_ATTR_VALUE FROM UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE, UM_USER WHERE UM_USER.UM_ID = UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_USER_ID AND UM_USER.UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_ATTR_NAME=? AND UM_PROFILE_ID=? AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserLisForPropertySQL">SELECT UM_USER_NAME FROM UM_USER, UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE WHERE UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_USER_ID = UM_USER.UM_ID AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_ATTR_NAME =? AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_ATTR_VALUE =? AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_PROFILE_ID=? AND UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_USER.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetProfileNamesSQL">SELECT DISTINCT UM_PROFILE_ID FROM UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE WHERE UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserProfileNamesSQL">SELECT DISTINCT UM_PROFILE_ID FROM UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserIDFromUserNameSQL">SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetUserNameFromTenantIDSQL">SELECT UM_USER_NAME FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="GetTenantIDFromUserNameSQL">SELECT UM_TENANT_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=?</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserSQL">INSERT INTO UM_USER (UM_USER_NAME, UM_USER_PASSWORD, UM_SALT_VALUE, UM_REQUIRE_CHANGE, UM_CHANGED_TIME, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserToRoleSQL">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ROLE (UM_USER_ID, UM_ROLE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES ((SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?),(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), ?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddRoleSQL">INSERT INTO UM_ROLE (UM_ROLE_NAME, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES (?, ?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddSharedRoleSQL">UPDATE UM_ROLE SET UM_SHARED_ROLE = ? WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME = ? AND UM_TENANT_ID = ?</Property>
          <Property name="AddRoleToUserSQL">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ROLE (UM_ROLE_ID, UM_USER_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES ((SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?),(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), ?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddSharedRoleToUserSQL">INSERT INTO UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE (UM_ROLE_ID, UM_USER_ID, UM_USER_TENANT_ID, UM_ROLE_TENANT_ID) VALUES ((SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?),(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), ?, ?)</Property>
          <Property name="RemoveUserFromSharedRoleSQL">DELETE FROM UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE WHERE   UM_ROLE_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_USER_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_ROLE_TENANT_ID = ?</Property>
          <Property name="RemoveUserFromRoleSQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER_ROLE WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_ROLE_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="RemoveRoleFromUserSQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="DeleteRoleSQL">DELETE FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME = ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="OnDeleteRoleRemoveUserRoleMappingSQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="DeleteUserSQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME = ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="OnDeleteUserRemoveUserRoleMappingSQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER_ROLE WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="OnDeleteUserRemoveUserAttributeSQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="UpdateUserPasswordSQL">UPDATE UM_USER SET UM_USER_PASSWORD= ?, UM_SALT_VALUE=?, UM_REQUIRE_CHANGE=?, UM_CHANGED_TIME=? WHERE UM_USER_NAME= ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="UpdateRoleNameSQL">UPDATE UM_ROLE set UM_ROLE_NAME=? WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME = ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserPropertySQL">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE (UM_USER_ID, UM_ATTR_NAME, UM_ATTR_VALUE, UM_PROFILE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES ((SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), ?, ?, ?, ?)</Property>
          <Property name="UpdateUserPropertySQL">UPDATE UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE SET UM_ATTR_VALUE=? WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_ATTR_NAME=? AND UM_PROFILE_ID=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="DeleteUserPropertySQL">DELETE FROM UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?) AND UM_ATTR_NAME=? AND UM_PROFILE_ID=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenantsSQL">SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=?</Property>
          <Property name="IsDomainExistingSQL">SELECT UM_DOMAIN_ID FROM UM_DOMAIN WHERE UM_DOMAIN_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="AddDomainSQL">INSERT INTO UM_DOMAIN (UM_DOMAIN_NAME, UM_TENANT_ID) VALUES (?, ?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserToRoleSQL-mssql">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ROLE (UM_USER_ID, UM_ROLE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) SELECT (SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?),(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?),(?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddRoleToUserSQL-mssql">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ROLE (UM_ROLE_ID, UM_USER_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) SELECT (SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_ROLE WHERE UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?),(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), (?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserPropertySQL-mssql">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE (UM_USER_ID, UM_ATTR_NAME, UM_ATTR_VALUE, UM_PROFILE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) SELECT (SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?), (?), (?), (?), (?)</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserToRoleSQL-openedge">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ROLE (UM_USER_ID, UM_ROLE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) SELECT UU.UM_ID, UR.UM_ID, ? FROM UM_USER UU, UM_ROLE UR WHERE UU.UM_USER_NAME=? AND UU.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UR.UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UR.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="AddRoleToUserSQL-openedge">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ROLE (UM_ROLE_ID, UM_USER_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) SELECT UR.UM_ID, UU.UM_ID, ? FROM UM_ROLE UR, UM_USER UU WHERE UR.UM_ROLE_NAME=? AND UR.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UU.UM_USER_NAME=? AND UU.UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="AddUserPropertySQL-openedge">INSERT INTO UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE (UM_USER_ID, UM_ATTR_NAME, UM_ATTR_VALUE, UM_PROFILE_ID, UM_TENANT_ID) SELECT UM_ID, ?, ?, ?, ? FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME=? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?</Property>
          <Property name="DomainName">PRIMARY</Property>
          <Property name="Description"/>
    </UserStoreManager>
```

And, in master-datasources.xml:

```
    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000</url>
                <username>wso2carbon</username>
                <password>wso2carbon</password>
                <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>

    <datasource>
        <name>JDBC_User_Store</name>
        <description>The datasource used for JDBC_User_Store</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/JDBC_User_Store</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JDBC_User_Store</url>
                <username>root</username>
                <password>root</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```

I hope it will be helpful.

PD: In your user-mgt.xml I miss the next:

```
<Property name="driverName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Property>
<Property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JDBC_User_Store</Property>
<Property name="userName">root</Property>
<Property name="password">root</Property>
```

And:

```
<Propertyname="MultiTenantRealmConfigBuilder">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.multitenancy.SimpleRealmConfigBuilder</Property>
```

Remember put the MySQL driver (.jar) in /repository/components/lib directory.

Comment: Hi Sergio,Thanks for your help.  I did read Pushpalanka's blog article and it was very helpful as well. I have made the changes you suggested except the H2 datasource. I am hoping to be able to only use MySQL to login. Is it a requirement to use an H2 datasource?

Comment: I don't know :S. But If you use H2 datasource too you can see the identity server use MySQL to login and to store users.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to use mysql as primary user store on a fresh IS pack. Without getting into specifics what you need to do is,

1) create a mysql database

2) put the database config in IS_HOME/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml

3) comment out

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
```

element and its children in IS_HOME/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml

4) uncomment

```
<!--UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
```

in above mentioned file

5) replace the value of

```
<Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
```

with jndi value specified in master-datasources.xml for new database

6) copy mysql jdbc driver to IS_HOME/repository/components/lib

7) start server with -Dsetup